# Passive voice grammar

Tags: passive-voice

I have a question about passive voice. I want my sentence to mean: "I took a punishment".

Which one is correct?

1. The punishment was given to me.
2. I was given punishment.

Comment: I received punishment.

Comment: I was punished - it's simpler.

Comment: "I received punishment." sounds a bit more formal, though both can be used in a formal context.

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatical, as *give* is a ditransitive verb.

As Rogermue says in a comment, "I was punished" is much more common than either.